# POST becomes GET after htaccess directives

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, post, get

I am hiding the php file extention using the below directives in Apache htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

I have a simple html form like this

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And in my PHP page this is how I was earlier checking whether the form has been posted

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
/* code to process the post */
}
```

But since I added the htaccess directives to hide the php filename extensionthe "POST" becomes "GET" and the above code never executes. Is there a good way to handle this? I know it is the internal redirect that causes this but is there an elegant way to handle this? I don't want to use the below method for obvious reasons

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate the problem you describe -

Comment: It should not be difficult to replicate it I guess. You will need to put the first block of rules in your htaccess file. Then create a php page with the 2nd block of code and just above the code for html form put in my 3rd block of code with the REQUEST_METHOD - and just put in an alert or a console message in the IF condition. You can see that it won't fire because it is expecting a reply (POST) from server but it gets a GET due to the redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POST` doesn't become `GET`, it is due to your first redirect rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
```

Which is catching a request with `.php` in it and redirecting to a URL without `.php` in it. You're looking at `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` **after it has been redirected by this rule**.

To fix have it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

i.e. don't redirect `POST` requests to avoid `POST` data getting lost.

Comment: I did mention that "I know it is the internal redirect that causes this" but if I don't do the redirect then the link shows up as https://myapp.example.com/register.php ( and I prefer not to display the extension for all my pages). It's weird to display page extension for some pages and not for others. Thanks

Comment: No it is not **internal redirect**, it is an external redirect that causes a new GET request being issued from browser to webserver. `POST` requests are not supposed to be redirected otherwise you will loose all of your POST data. To hide `.php` you can just change `action` parameter as: **`<form action="register" method="post">`**

Comment: cool thanks, it works without having to change action parameter because after the submit it's a GET request so the extension doesn't show up anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has the problem with **ajax call**.

In this case I had a rewrite rule with [L,R]. It must be only [L] otherwise "POST becomes GET".